# Syntax error on my member initializer lists

Tags: c++, c++11, makefile

I have the following class:

```cpp
class MathNode {
  protected:
  std::list<std::pair<std::string, MathNode*> > myChildren;
 
  public:
  MathNode()
    : myChildren{} // line 15
  {} // line 16
  MathNode(std::string l, MathNode* c)
    : myChildren{ std::make_pair(l, c) }
  {}
  MathNode(std::string l1, MathNode* c1,
           std::string l2, MathNode* c2)
    : myChildren{ std::make_pair(l1, c1),
                  std::make_pair(l2, c2) }
  {}
};
```

And when I go to compile I get the following errors:

```
In file included from ./calc.hpp:6:
./nodes.hpp:16:9: error: expected member name or ';' after declaration
      specifiers
        {}
        ^
./nodes.hpp:15:25: error: expected '('
            : myChildren{}
```

I tried changing the curlies to parenthesis on line 15, and got these errors:

```
In file included from ./calc.hpp:6:
./nodes.hpp:19:9: error: expected member name or ';' after declaration
      specifiers
        {}
        ^
./nodes.hpp:18:25: error: expected '('
            : myChildren{ std::make_pair(l, c) }
                        ^
./nodes.hpp:18:47: error: expected ';' after expression
            : myChildren{ std::make_pair(l, c) }
```

As far as I can tell, I'm using perfectly legal C++11 syntax, and I even explicitly passed the option to use C++11 in my Makefile. What gives?

EDIT: We've narrowed down the issue to a Makefile problem. Here's the Makefile:

```
all: calc test

calc: parser.o lexer.o calc.o
    g++ -std=c++11 -g -o calc calc.o lexer.o parser.o

test: calc
    ./calc input.txt

%.o: %.cpp
    g++ -std=c++11 -g -c $<

lexer.o: lexer.yy.cc
    g++ -std=c++11 -g -c $< -o lexer.o

lexer.yy.cc: grammar.hh lexer.l
    flex --outfile lexer.yy.cc lexer.l

grammar.hh: parser.yy
    bison --defines=grammar.hh -d -v parser.yy

parser.cc: grammar.hh

.PHONY: clean test

clean:
    rm -rf *.o *.cc *.hh calc parser.output
```

EDIT: I solved this in an answer below.

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/rzhhTqq3n). What compiler, including version?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat `Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)`

Comment: UPDATE: I've gotten the file to compile itself by using the `-std=c++11` option in a command outside of my makefile. That means somehow this is not being specified in some command in my makefile. I am using Bison for this project so I will have to look into it a little more.

Comment: @Andymang it would help if you showed your actual makefile

Comment: I've added the makefile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add a rule for parser.o to compile parser.cc:

```
parser.o: parser.cc
    g++ -std=c++11 -g -c $< -o parser.o
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::list` has its own default constructor, so your default constructor does not need to explicitly initialize `myChildren` at all, eg:

```
MathNode() {}
```

Or, in C++11 and later:

```
MathNode() = default;
```

In your other constructors, you need C++11 or later to use the initialization syntax you want.  As you deduced, you are not compiling for C++11, which is why you are getting errors on C++11 syntax.  You need to fix your makefile to enable C++11 properly.

Otherwise, just use `push_back()` inside the constructor bodies instead, eg:

```
MathNode(std::string l, MathNode* c)
{
    myChildren.push_back( std::make_pair(l, c) );
}

MathNode(std::string l1, MathNode* c1,
         std::string l2, MathNode* c2)
{
    myChildren.push_back( std::make_pair(l1, c1) );
    myChildren.push_back( std::make_pair(l2, c2) );
}
```